# Vim keeps asking to press enter before start

Tags: vim

I started editing .vimrc but ever since I did that vim keep on asking me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before it opens. I am not sure why? I does not display any warnings just that message

Here is .vimrc:

```
1 " Text Apperance
2 set number
3 set syntax
4 set showmatch
5 
6 " Errors Alerts
7 set visualbell
8 set errorbells
9 
10 " Search
11 set hlsearch
12 set ignorecase
13 
14 " Indentation
15 set autoindent
16 set expandtab
17 set shiftwidth=2
18 set softtabstop=2
19 
20 " StatusBar
21 set ruler
22 
23 " Colorscheme
24 colorscheme distinguished
```

Comment: What is the exact wording Vim uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your vimrc by creating a test file `test-vimrc` and loading it with `vim -u test-vimrc`. By [commenting out](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:comment) lines with `"` at the beginning, I found out that the problem is this line:

```
set syntax
```

`set syntax` shows the value of the [`'syntax'` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27syntax%27), which represents the name of the syntax highlighting language you want for this buffer. It does this according to the `:se[t] {option}` syntax of the [`:set` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set):

> ```
> :se[t] {option}         Toggle option: set, switch it on.
>                         Number option: show value.
>                         String option: show value.
> ```

`'syntax'` is a string option, and its default value is the empty string. So when running `set syntax`, Vim prints an empty string, and then asks you to press ENTER once you have read the text.

What you really want is [`syntax on`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syntax-on), which switches on syntax highlighting. So change the line to this to fix it:

```
syntax on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `set shortmess=a` to solve this problem.